# LESS CSS guard expression matching string

Tags: css, string, less, guard

I want to apply background color to some element in case the value is the string 'red'. I search the web and found out that I cannot use <, >, <=, >= on strings and = behaves differently.

```
.myfunction(@PLACEHOLDER_COLOR) when (@PLACEHOLDER_COLOR = 'red') {
  background-color:red;
}


.bullet:hover,
.bullet.selected
{.myfunction(@COLOR_SETTING)}
```

Does anyone know how to check if that value equals the string?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

### Watch Your Passed-in Value

What you have is correct for LESS. But what you are passing in as a value in your call to it may not be.

**This will work**:

```
@COLOR_SETTING: 'red'; // or "red"
```

**This will not** (as it is not the string "red" but the LESS color value of `red`):

```
@COLOR_SETTING: red;
```

### Other Options

**If you are going to be passing in color values instead of strings**, then change your mixin to this:

```
.myfunction(@PLACEHOLDER_COLOR) when (@PLACEHOLDER_COLOR = red) {
  background-color:red;
}
```

Which would also accept input such as `#f00`.

**If you want to accept either string or color input**, this will work (but it will throw a LESS error if the value cannot be made into a color):

```
.myfunction(@PLACEHOLDER_COLOR) when (color("@{PLACEHOLDER_COLOR}") = red) {
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: I was sending other value to @COLOR_SETTING that's why the guard was failing. Thank you